# How to solve this error Array to string conversion - in laravel inertia vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I am facing an issue with my code when using multiselect. When I use multiselect, I encounter a problem, but when I don't use multiselect, the data is saved correctly. I am using Laravel, Vue.js, and Inertia.js.

This is my component:

```
<script setup>
import AdminLayout from "@/Layouts/AdminLayout.vue";
import { Head, Link, useForm } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import VueMultiselect from 'vue-multiselect';
import { defineProps } from 'vue';

defineProps({
  employee: Array,
})
const form = useForm({
employee: [],
description: "",
 });
```

```
    <Head title="پرداخت معاش " />
    <div class="w-full mx-auto mt-6 p-6 bg-white shadow">
        <form @submit.prevent="form.post(route('salaries.store'))">
            <div class="grid grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-4">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="employee" class="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">نام
                        </label>
                    <div class="mt-2">
                        <VueMultiselect
                            v-model="form.employee"
                            :options="employee"
                            :searchable="true"
                            :close-on-select="true"
                            :clear-on-select="false"
                            :preserve-search="false"
                            placeholder="انتخاب کنید"
                            track-by="id"
                            label="name"
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 mt-3">
                <InputLabel for="description" value="توضیحات" />
                <textarea rows="3" placeholder="توضیحات" class="w-full form-control" v-model="form.description"
                    required></textarea>
                <InputError class="mt-2" :message="form.errors.description" />
            </div>
            <div class="w-full flex items-center mt-4">
                <PrimaryButton class="ml-4" :class="{ 'opacity-25': form.processing }" :disabled="form.processing">
                    ثبت معاش
                </PrimaryButton>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
</AdminLayout>
```

This is my controller code:

```
public function store(Request $request): RedirectResponse
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'employee' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
    ]);

    $salary = new Salary();
    $salary->employee_id = $validatedData['employee'];
    $salary->description = $validatedData['description'];

    $salary->save();

    return redirect()->route('salaries.index')->with('message', 'عملیه با موفقیت انجام شد.');
}
```

When I submit the data, I encounter the "Array to string conversion" error.

Comment: Please provide the errors (as text) inside the question as well - [ask]

Comment: When I submit the data, I encounter the "Array to string conversion" error.

Comment: Errors say much more than that, for starts it also mentions the line which throws that notice. So please paste the full error and not only the message you are receiving. "*When I use multiselect*" - Of course you will have multiple values leading to an array, it's up to you to handle this and think about on how you want to store the multiple values, rather than one value.